# How do I identify an email address from a long string and replace the email address with my company's email address?

Tags: c#, regex

The question is not only about identifying email address from a string. It is about replacing the found email address with the company email address.

For eg. if i have a string as below:

"Hi, My name is John Martin. I am a painter and sculptor. If you wish to purchase my paintings please look at my portfolio on the site and then contact me on **john@gmail.com**"

I would like to replace the above string with

"Hi, My name is John Martin. I am a painter and sculptor. If you wish to purchase my paintings please look at my portfolio on the site and then contact me on **support@companyname.com**"

Comment: Is it always `john@gmail.com`?

Comment: no.. it could be carlnorum@gmail.com also.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will replace all email strings that match the patern with your email id, the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class can be found in [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx) namespace

```
Regex emailReplace = new Regex(@"[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
emailReplace.Replace("YOUR TEXT HERE", "support@companyname.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String GetEMailAddresses(string Input)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection MC = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(Input, "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*");

    if(MC.Count > 0)
        return MC[0].Value;

    return "";
}
```

You can find email address using above method. If it returns something other than "" it means it's an email address. Now you can simply use String.Replace method to replace old with with new email address

```
string input = "Hi, My name is John Martin. I am a painter and sculptor. If you wish to purchase my paintings please look at my portfolio on the site and then contact me on support@companyname.com";
            string email = GetEMailAddresses(input);
            input = input.Replace(email, "support@companyname.com");
```